# Computing: How to say "optional parameters"

Tags: translation, computing

In programming, a function can have [optional parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_programming%29#Default_arguments), for instance getTemperature() could have an optional parameter "Unit" to say I want the temperature in Kelvin for instance. By default, when specifying no parameter, it would be in Celsius.

How to say `optional parameters` in Japanese?

ALC says `オプションのパラメータ`:

> Both required and optional parameters are listed.
>   必須なパラメータおよびオプションのパラメータを列挙します。

But I believe they are wrong, and their translation has a different meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for

> 必須（の/な）引数 => required parameter(s).

and

> 任意（の/な）引数 => optional parameter(s)